# nginx and uwsgi and Django gives 500 error

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have been stuck for several hours on trying to make this configuration work. Here are my below configuration details:

```
[uwsgi]
uid = ubuntu
gid = ubuntu

plugins = python3 
wsgi-file = /home/ubuntu/core/core/wsgi.py
virtualenv = /home/ubuntu/virtual
chdir = /home/ubuntu/core
home = /home/ubuntu/virtual 
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=core.settings
socket = /run/uwsgi/app.sock
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
module = core.wsgi:application
chown-socket = ubuntu:ubuntu
chmod-socket = 666
enable-threads = True
```

and for nginx:

```
# nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    location /static {
        root /home/ubuntu/core/assets;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/run/uwsgi/app.sock;
    }
}
```

I'm not seeing any error in logs but it still says 500 error. I have read the documentation thoroughly on uwsgi and nginx. Is there something im missing? Any help appreciated!

***EDIT 1***

Here is my `LOGGING` from Django side:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '[%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(thread)d] '
                      '%(module)s:%(funcName)s - %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
        'loggly': {
            'format': 'loggly: %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
        },
        "mail_admins": {
            "level": "ERROR",
            "filters": ["require_debug_false"],
            "class": "django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler",
            "include_html": True,
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler'
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'filename': str(Path(BASE_DIR, 'logs', 'django.log').resolve()),
            'when': 'midnight',
            'interval': 1
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.security.DisallowedHost': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'main': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'console', 'mail_admins'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with uwsgi logging, so I'm not sure what %n in  ```/var/log/uwsgi/%n.log``` does, but even is uwsgi is properly writing to a log file, you probably won't see the exact error, only *that* an error occured. 

500 means that the service is running correctly, but that an error occured when processing your request. You'll need to look in the Django logging. What is value of ```LOGGING``` in the Django settings?

Comment: Updated with Django logging.

Comment: Share nginx logs in `/var/log/nginx/*.log`

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to see the 500 error logged in the ```django.log``` file?

Comment: It was a permissions issue! Thanks for the help.